# What could be the reason for getting low contrast in GAN generated images?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, convolution, dc-gan

I am trying to use DCGAN for the waterbirds dataset with the following hyperparameters, but I am getting low-contrast images. It would be great if anyone has any suggestions as to what could be some usual reasons for such an outcome.

```
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-4 
BATCH_SIZE = 64
IMAGE_SIZE = 64
CHANNELS_IMG = 3
NOISE_DIM = 150
NUM_EPOCHS = 150
```

Comment: This could be anything from too few epochs, wrong noise_dim, to that model just plain doesn't get better than this. Is there any indication it should perform better? did you follow parameter settings from somewhere? this question needs more information.